# How to compare published and project code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, publishing

There is a website VS project.

This was published and deployed to client server a year back.

Now there is a bug and before fixing we need to make sure that our dev version is same as that on the server. Problem is we have the project code and on LIVE server it is the published code.

Please advice how to compare the two.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't straightforward. You can't compare the binaries easily. They are different for every build.

Comment: @variable  You can use ilspy http://ilspy.net/

Comment: @wizkid: Yes, you could extract the IL from all the binaries both sides and diff. Fairly painful, but I'm not sure you can do much better than that.

Comment: Did nobody on the team write down which source control revision was being published to production?  That's... usually a good thing to keep track of.

Comment: For the future: create branches so that you can always have the source code of what is deployed.

Comment: On each deployment usually i take backup of both the running copy and a copy of upcomming version :)

Comment: Branches aren't really necessary.  All you need is the source control revision identifier.  You can just grab that specific revision and branch if necessary when making a change.  Additionally, frequent deployments significantly reduce the need for unnecessary branches by allowing hot fixes to be addressed in the main codebase in smaller increments.

Comment: will i get to see the code behind using ILSPY? I have downloaded the ILSPY.net what to I evaluate in this>

Comment: But branches make it easy to fix bugs and deploy that exact version; and optionally merge these changes back into the dev and main branch, for example.

Comment: @variable: Yes. But you won't get you back your exact original source code - it will be decompiled from the IL. You'll have to run ILSpy on *both* the server binaries, *and* your dev binaries, and compare the outputs.

Comment: Why not publish to a temporary location, then zip that location up and hash it using MD5 or something similar.  Then zip up the production published location and hash that.  If the codebase has changed, that should tell you.

Comment: WHich binary can you tell me please. you mean every files in the BIN folder?

Comment: @variable: Yes, every compiled binary.  (Or at least the ones that would change between application versions.)  And even then they still probably wouldn't be identical.  As you can imagine, comparing all of them manually isn't a small task.  This is why it's best to keep track of which version of the application is published to which environment.

Comment: @L-Three: Right, and a branch can be made when that fix is needed.  It's not necessary to create a branch with *every* deployment, only when one needs to work in a separate branch.  (If there are hot fix issues on every deployment then I would argue that there are more significant problems than source control policies.)  Though still, in a continuous integration and continuous deployment environment (or at least rapid deployment), hot fixes can just be made directly on the codebase and included in a new deployment.

Comment: @David: indeed, you're right.